# Move from xib to storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I have an app that has a single XIB file for the interface. I'd like to move to storyboard. I've created the storyboard, add all of the relevant UI elements and linked them to the header file (IBoutlets). I've gone to my project summary and selected my storyboard in the iPad deployment section.

My problem is that the app is still using the XIB, rather than my storyboard. Any ideas?

Comment: have you changed the application delegate to not use the xib?

Comment: re-do the interface builder, don't copy. Did this once, made a mess. It's not that hard and i think its worth it.

Comment: I recreated the app UI again from scratch in storyboard, but it's not being used. It's still using the XIB.

Comment: @user1542125 in you `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` remove all the code and only keep `return YES;`

Comment: Thanks, that has got me further. I'm now getting the following error: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from Xib to Storyboard is still buggy...
Delete the App manually from your iPhone/simulator or restore the simulator. Clear your Project, etc. Maybe you have to restart Xcode too.

Comment: Have tried all of the above but I'm still seeing the XIB, not the storyboard.

Comment: When you switched in 'Project Summay' from Xib to Storyboard, you have to check if in 'Project Info' (the next Tab) that there is no 'Main nib file base name' Key!